# Duplicate records during a foreach loop

Tags: php, sql

I have a query that pulls news stories, then attaches any photos connected with a particular story. This all works fine but I recently added a feature to also pull videos conected with stories and it causes duplicate images or video links to show.

Example, I have a news story with 3 pictures and 1 video. Currently it posts that one video next to each picture so it shows up 3 times. What I actually want to display is the news story, then any pictures, then any videos.

Here is the php

```
$sLastStory = '';
foreach ($result AS $row)
{
    $sStory = $row['headline'] . $row['story'];
    if (strcasecmp($sStory, $sLastStory) != 0)
    {
        if (!empty($sLastStory))
        {
            print('<hr>' . PHP_EOL);
        }
        $sLastStory = $sStory;


        printf('<h2>%s</h2>' . PHP_EOL, $row['headline']);

        printf('<a href="parknews.php?park_id=%s">
        <h3>%s</a> - %s</h3>' . PHP_EOL, $row['park_id'], $row['name'], $row['Displaydate']);

        printf('<p>%s</p>' . PHP_EOL, $row['story']);
    }

if(!empty($row['url'])){   
printf('
<a href="/images/%s%s.jpg" rel="lightbox[%s]" title="%s - Credit - %s" >
<img src="/images/%s%s-thumb.jpg" style="min-height: 200px; min-width: 200px" alt="%s"/></a>' . PHP_EOL, $row['url'], $row['alt'], $row['headline'],  $row['description'],$row['credit'], $row['url'], $row['alt'], $row['alt'] );
}

if(!empty($row['location'])){   
printf('<iframe width="640" height="360" src="%s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' . PHP_EOL, $row['location'] );
}

}
```

I'm not great with PHP and just copied this part:

```
if(!empty($row['url'])){   
printf('
<a href="/images/%s%s.jpg" rel="lightbox[%s]" title="%s - Credit - %s" >
<img src="/images/%s%s-thumb.jpg" style="min-height: 200px; min-width: 200px" alt="%s"/></a>' . PHP_EOL, $row['url'], $row['alt'], $row['headline'],  $row['description'],$row['credit'], $row['url'], $row['alt'], $row['alt'] );
}
```

then pasted it underneath but changed it for the videos query instead of images.
Any ideas how to fix it to display correctly?
Thanks

edit: this is the query

```
try
{
$sql = 'SELECT headline, story, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%M-%Y") AS Displaydate, name, logo, tpf_parks.park_id, url, alt, description, credit, location
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id 
LEFT JOIN tpf_images ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_images.news_id 
LEFT JOIN tpf_videos ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_videos.news_id 
ORDER BY date DESC' ;
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Please post the query you use to retrieve these rows, I suspect you have a cross join going on.

Comment: From what I can see it looks like it might be an issue with your SQL statement that if it keeps pulling up both.  But it would be best to use two separate statements and loop through them individually.  One for the pictures, one for the video.

Comment: just edit question - query is now there.

Comment: also to see the problem in action its happening on the first news story here: www.themeparkfocus.com/news/

Comment: Based on your SQL, what differentiates the video url from the image url?  You don't specify that in your query.

Comment: the video urls are called 'location' in the tpf_videos table and image urls are split into two parts in tpf-images called 'url' and 'alt'. So there should be no naming crossover

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without doing some actual testing, but I’d try processing your `$result` through `array_unique($result)` and see if that doesn’t eliminate the duplicates.

As others have said above, see if you can `print_r($result)` for us and maybe we can figure out what’s going on. Also post the SQL fetch line if you can.

Comment: If `array_unique` would solve this problem, the SQL statement needs to be better written rather than using this function.

Comment: @Jon: Agreed, but this is one line of code to troubleshoot vs. rewriting an entire SQL query.

Comment: As mentioned I am not great with coding! How do I do print_r($result)?

Answer (score 0):

The way the SQL is written, it is returning one row for each photo or
video, but video row also includes a link to a photo, or vice versa.
What you really want is a `UNION`, which expresses your intent to show
the sum of photo and videos. I would recommend using two queries. The
first would just get the story details.

The second would get the photos and videos. You could then merge the
data structures based on the news_id.

```sql
 SELECT tpf_news_id, ... FROM tpf_images JOIN tpf_news ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_images.news_id
 UNION
 SELECT tpf_news_id, ... FROM tpf_videos JOIN tpf_news ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_videos.news_id;
```

When you use `UNION`, you'll need to make sure you output the same name
and number of colums in both queries.

In your code, you can loop over the news items and then have an inner
loop for photos and videos, without the duplicate checking to see if
this news story is a duplicate of the last.

Comment: Is there any chance you could mash this together. I've never used UNION before and I'm a novice at best. It sounds like I need to change a lot. Thanks

Comment: Yes, in each part of the UNION you could also select the headline, story, etc. All rows would contain the story details, and then either image details and empty video details, or empty image details but video details. Your code would remain more similar to what you have now. I don't feel that this as clearly expresses your intent, but it would work. Give UNION a shot, I think you'll find it fairly easy. Assuming MySQL, here are some docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html